# Panoramica Theme Portfolio

Tags: categories

I am using panoramica theme for my WordPress website. I want to show the portfolio with category "Meet the team" along with other post category in one page. How can it be possible. Now I am able to show the post of a specific category in one page.I need to add Posrtfolio page to this. below is the code I used to show the post of a specific category in one page.

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: Custom Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header();

    $recent = new WP_Query("cat=4&posts_per_page=5"); 
    while($recent->have_posts()):$recent->the_post();

     the_content(); 

    endwhile;


 get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To show posts from multiple categories on the same page, use

```
$recent = new WP_Query( 'cat=2,6,17,38&posts_per_page=5' );
```

Comment: The portfolio have no category. It have `taxonomy=cpo_tax_portfolio&tag_ID=3&post_type=cpo_portfolio`

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear from your question.